# How to set the initial default value of dropdown in knockout js

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, knockout.js

Here is my code in View

```
<select data-bind="options:TypeInfo,optionsText: 'PrefName',
        optionsValue: 'PrefName',value: $data.selectedchoice,event:
        {change:gettrivialtable}" class="forms-dropdown"></select>
```

Here is my Js Code

```
viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(viewData);

self.TypeInfo = viewModel.TypeInfo;

self.selectedchoice = ko.observable('');
```

Note : viewData is a Json Pushed from model.`PrefName` is a property of the `TypeInfo` class. The value returned are `0:'x',1:'y',2:'select'` in the same order I want `'select'` to be the default value. Please help me out.

Comment: Please post your gettrivialtable function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could set your selectedchoice with variable from TypeInfo like:

```
self.selectedchoice(self.TypeInfo()[0])
```

or very similar

Comment: Well it worked thanks a lot!!!!!!!!!!! the soln was        self.selectedchoice(self.TypeInfo()[0].PrefName())

Answer (score 1):

If you define your self.selectedChoice observable as

```
self.selectedchoice = ko.observable('select');
```

the select list will default to that option.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with what you've got so far and we can get this working for you.